# Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am passing some parameter to api , to done add to cart function. But when i pass the parameter , it showing the crash `Invalid top-level type in JSON write'` i know there is the problem in my passing parameter . Please help me out!.How to do that.Please help me out !!!

This is the json format of parameter i am passing !!:

```
{
    "cartType" : "1",
    "cartDetails" : {
        "customerID" : "u",
        "cartAmount" : "6999",  
        "cartShipping" : "1",
        "cartTax1" : "69",
        "cartTax2" : "",
        "cartTax3" : "",
        "cartCouponCode" : "",
        "cartCouponAmount" : "",
        "cartPaymentMethod" : "",
        "cartProductItems" : {
            "productID" : "9",
            "productPrice" : "6999",
            "productQuantity" : "1"
        }
    }
}
```

My updated solution  :

```
func addtocartapicalling ()
{
    let headers = [
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
    ]

    let jsonObj:Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        "cartType" : "1",
        "cartDetails" : [
            "customerID" : "sathish",
            "cartAmount" : "6999",
            "cartShipping" : "1",
            "cartTax1" : "69",
            "cartTax2" : "",
            "cartTax3" : "",
            "cartCouponCode" : "",
            "cartCouponAmount" : "",
            "cartPaymentMethod" : "",
            "cartProductItems" : [
                "productID" : "9",
                "productPrice" : "6999",
                "productQuantity" : "1"
            ]
        ]
    ]

    if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObj)) {
        print("is not a valid json object")
        return
    }

    if let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://expapi.php")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                ///print(error)
            } else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    {
                        let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                        if(status == 1)
                        {
                            print("SUCCESS....")
                            if (json["CartID"] as? Int?) != nil
                            {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                    print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")
                                    self.addtocartdata.append(Addtocartmodel(json:CartID))


                                })
                            }

                        }

                    }
                })

            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

last problem in append the values :

[image]

In my model data class is look like this  :

```
class Addtocartmodel

{
 var cartid : Int?
init(json:NSDictionary)
    {
         self.cartid = json["CartID"] as? Int
}
}
```

Comment: so what the actual reason of error u getting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your json has some wrong format.Use a dictionary is much clear than json in swift, and use JSONSerialization to convert the dictionary to json string.

The code looks like this:

```
func addtocartapicalling ()
{
    let headers = [
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
    ]

    let jsonObj:Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        "cartType" : "1",
        "cartDetails" : [
            "customerID" : "sathish",
            "cartAmount" : "6999",
            "cartShipping" : "1",
            "cartTax1" : "69",
            "cartTax2" : "",
            "cartTax3" : "",
            "cartCouponCode" : "",
            "cartCouponAmount" : "",
            "cartPaymentMethod" : "",
            "cartProductItems" : [
                "productID" : "9",
                "productPrice" : "6999",
                "productQuantity" : "1"
            ]
        ]
    ]

    if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObj)) {
        print("is not a valid json object")
        return
    }

    if let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://expapi.php")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    {
                        let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                        if(status == 1)
                        {
                            print("SUCCESS....")
                            print(json)
                            if let CartID = json["CartID"] as? Int {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                    print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")
                                    print("CartID:\(CartID)")
                                    self.addtocartdata.append(Addtocartmodel(json:json))
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: So the jsonstr is my parameter to pass to api right >>

Comment: I am new to ios, i dont know how to do that http method to pass to my api. Can you please edit your solution with my do catch thing also. So that it will be helpfull to understand the flow of it

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have use it. after passing the parameter to api, i will get the `{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Cart values has been added successfully.",
  "CartID": 5
}` like this. But i am not getting it and also not getting in my db also

Comment: And i need to store this cartID Value or else have to append to my model data class.

Comment: Yes, now i get the cart id. But when i do append its not appending in my model data class value

Comment: Check the parameter type of Addtocartmodel, maybe just call `self.addtocartdata.append(Addtocartmodel(json:json))`

Comment: whats is that` json:json`, how it will append only the cartID to my `Addtocartmodel`

Comment: The Addtocartmodel did it self. Check the Addtocartmodel code. It get cartID from a json dictionary.

Comment: i did, but when i run and see its not printing the cart value in my console and not printing the append value too ??

Comment: I ma getting only success ... print statement. And the code ` print("INSIDE CATEGORIES")
                                        print("CartID:\(CartID)")` is not printing in my console too. Its mean that , that code is not executing right ??

Comment: yes i am getting the response `["CartID": 15, "status": 1, "message": Cart values has been added successfully.]
INSIDE CATEGORIES
CartID:15
CartID:()`. But when i try to see the append value. It coming like this = `CartID:()`

Answer (score 13):

**There is a subtle difference**

Try using this

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

instead of

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

Comment: please help to solve this Cannot invoke jsonObject with an argument list of type '(with:Any, options: [Any])'

Comment: Try one of these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/43986831/5438240