# Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, swift3

When using this code to get JSON from a server with Basic auth:

```
                    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let userPasswordData = "\(username!):\(password!)".data(using: .utf8)
        let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
        let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let url = URL(string: "https://theforest.academy/api/v1/auth")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil {


                do {
                    if let data = data {
                       // let json1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [], error: []) as? [String: Any]
                        if(json["valid"]) {
                            print(json["token"])
                        } else {
                            print("Invalid login")
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
                }
```

I am getting the following error

> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with:
>   Data, options: [Any], error: [Any])'

Comment: You should be passing your data to the initializer not a string, why are you even creating a string from your data?

Comment: @dan I edited my answer to pass the data to the initializer and it gives the same error.

Comment: You have the correct syntax right there, in the comment `// let json1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]` ;)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html Error management has changed since Swift 2.2 I think. It's now a try/catch and the `error` parameter doesn't appear anymore in the "method call signature".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/), it seems that you only have two choices:

```
jsonObject(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = [])
```

And

```
jsonObject(with: InputStream, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = [])
```

I think you are looking for the first method. Perhaps you are confusing it with

```
writeJSONObject(Any, to: OutputStream, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = [], error: NSErrorPointer)
```

So, in short, such a method does not exist. That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Trying the first one gets me the following error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.Type'

Comment: @ScottyBlades, that is the signature of the method. It means that the options field has a default value of `[]` and it's of type `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions`. Normally you'd use it like `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)`, or `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [/*your options*/])`.

Comment: That is my understanding...but it doesn't explain why I would get this error.

Comment: It does, because you're doing something you're not supposed to. I specifically mentioned how you should call the method. You should have JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = [] somewhere in your code, i.e. assignment to an immutable expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is because we are not handling error while getting Data. So we need to safely type caste data and then pass it to JsonSerializer. Here is the code.

```
    do {
        let data = try NSData.init(contentsOfFile: path) as Data
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
        print(jsonArray)
    } catch {
        print("Error getting data")
    }
```