# Invalid top-level type in JSON write Swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to learn JSON parsing. I have written an API in Laravel, which returns `status : 200` in response. What I did is this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/workon-api/public/api/register") else { return }

    var request  = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let newUser = User.init(name: "Rob", email: "abc@gmail.com", password: "12345678")

    do {

        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newUser)

        request.httpBody = jsonBody

    } catch { }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)

            print(json)

        } catch {}

    }.resume()
```

Now, I am getting this error: `Invalid top-level type in JSON write` and app's crashing. After searching, I used this:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
```

And, it works. Why the previous method is not working? And, I get a response like this if I try to return the collected userInfo.

```
status = "{\"name\":\"Rob\",\"email\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"12345678\"}";
```

Why are back-slashes there? Are these okay? And, what is Gzip data? I know I am asking a lot, but I need to understand this. Thanks in advance.

P.S. : Here is the User Model.

```
struct User: Encodable {

let name            : String?

let email           : String?

let password        : String?

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to post the `User` model...

Comment: For the Invalid top-level type in JSON write . you might need to look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200002/invalid-top-level-type-in-json-write

Comment: Use `Codeable` instead if you are learning, the built in support for JSON in swift is very good and recommended by most. There is no point in learning a third party framework that might become obsolete.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson he already did that :) `let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newUser)` means he did. PS: It could be `Encodable` instead of `Codable`...

Comment: For your question on Why are back-slashes there? , look at this https://www.swiftyninja.com/escaped-string-json-using-swift/

Comment: @AhmadF, you're right but why mix them? The question seems to be about JSONSerialization so I repeat my recommendation to only use the built-in Json support.

Comment: @DvixExtract I have already the last answer to my query and it solves. I have mentioned that in the question above. But, I want to know why `try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)` is not working.

Comment: @AhmadF Added the User Model and I am not using any third party apps.

Comment: `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options)`: the first param needs to be a Dictionary or an Array object. And `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` wait for a `Data` object. You are misusing the good calls. The first one: Swift Array or Dictionary => JSONStringTransformedInData, the second one JSONStringTransformedInData => Swift Array or Dictionary

Comment: @Larme Thanks for making this clear.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the backslashes are virtual. The framework adds them to be able to `print` double quotes within a literal string.

Secondly `dataTask` returns serialized JSON `Data` so to get a dictionary or array from the data you have to call `jsonObject(with`.

```
let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
print(object)
```

Comment: Ok, though I removed the backslashes like this `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]`

Comment: Remove the `options` parameter like in my answer. *No options* is the default.

Comment: `No exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'`

Comment: @AndorNémeth This error is not related to a missing `options` parameter in Swift 3 and later.