# How to send body parameter in Alamofire in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, realm, alamofire

I have an api which consumes BODY parameter, like this

```
{"answers":[{"qid":2588,"value":["Free Society"]},{"qid":150,"value":["Closing of fSociety"]}],"uniqid":"t4815694"}
```

So what I have done is, I have created Data Model named `SubmitAnswerModel` like this which contains another Data Model named `QuestionAnswersToSubmit`

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

class SubmitAnswerModel: Object {

    var answers = [QuestionAnswersToSubmit]()
    @objc dynamic var uniqid: String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "uniqid"

    }


}



class QuestionAnswersToSubmit: Object {


    @objc dynamic var qid = 0
    var value = [String]()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "qid"

    }

}
```

So this object extends `RealmObject` and now I need to set values to this object and send it as BODY parameter in the api. I am doing it like this

```
func submitAnswerToApi() {

        guard let token = UserDefault().getLoginAccessTokenKey() else {
            print("No login token. Please relogin.")
            return
        }
        let answersToSubmit = SubmitAnswerModel() //main model
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let savedExamResponse = realm.object(ofType: SavedExamResponse.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
        answersToSubmit.uniqid = savedExamResponse?.uniqueId

        var answerListToSubmit =  [QuestionAnswersToSubmit]()

        for item in (savedExamResponse?.questionAnswerList)! {
            let answerToSubmit = QuestionAnswersToSubmit()
            answerToSubmit.qid =  item.questionId
            answerToSubmit.value = [item.selectedOption]            
            answerListToSubmit.append(answerToSubmit)

        }

        answersToSubmit.answers = answerListToSubmit

        let urlString = UrlCollection.submitAnswerUrl + "uniqid=" + answersToSubmit.uniqid! + "&token=" + token

        let param = answersToSubmit
        let uniqidParam = answersToSubmit.uniqid
        dump(param)


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(answersToSubmit)) {
            print("is not a valid json object")
            //return
        }

        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: answersToSubmit)

        Alamofire.request(request)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)

                    if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(responseString)
                    }
                case .success(let responseObject):
                    print(responseObject)
                }
        }


    }
```

So the problem now is, I am getting this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'`. What is the proper way to pass BODY parameter in SWIFT. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Json format could be wrong, please refer to this question:
[Invalid top-level type in JSON write'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200002/invalid-top-level-type-in-json-write)

Btw, the preferred way to set body using `Alamofire` is to pass a `Dictionary` to the parameters and then set encoding to `URLEncoding.httpbody`, like so:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

Alamofire.request("https://someapi/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpbody)
```